# How to run a thread for specific time in c#? Something like executing the same code again and again like a script for 5 seconds

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I want to run a thread, a small part of code to be executed for 5 seconds.

Execution should be only once, it should keep executing continuously for a specific time.

Note: It should not keep executing, something like a timer. Execution should be only once.

**Real Problem:**

There is a script called AHK. (Auto Hot Key).
It does some task like hiding a taskbar for specific time. 
I am not allowed to modify the script. 
I have to modify the same in application part(C#).

Sample Tried out codes:

```
void StartConnection()
{
stopwatch.Start();
Thread threadObj = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
threadObj.Start();
}

void ThreadFunc()
{
   for (; stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 6; )
   {
      WindowsNativeCalls.HideTaskbar();
   }
}
```

Is there any other dot net concept available to achieve this?

Comment: So you want to create a thread that runs your code? Then you create a thread and write the code it should run. Otherwise it's very unclear what the problem is. "Run for a specific time", "continuously" and "only once" is a bit contradicting without proper explanation.

Comment: added the real problem.

Comment: So run a loop on your thread that checks the elapsed time since start at the beginning of the loop... Have you tried writing this code?

Comment: Yeah i have tried it, just checking out is there any dot net concepts available to achieve this.

Comment: Approach would depend upon actual scenario. Do the running method gets notified from another method to stop ?

Comment: It sounds like your code will fully utilize one core of the processor for 6 seconds. Do you need to perform the action as often as possible? Maybe you could add a small delay in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

See if this fits your bill :

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { mycallBack(); });
        }

        private void mycallBack()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running !");

                if (stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= 5)
                    break;
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done !");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DispatcherTimer`

```
private DispatcherTimer myTimer;

private void StartMyTimer()
{
    if (myTimer != null)
        myTimer.Stop();

    myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);// You can change this for minutes, hours and etc
    myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;
    myTimer.Start();
}

void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here every 5 seconds
}
```

I hope this helps.